# Touch Events in Windows Phone 7 Mango IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7

Will the IE in WP7 Mango support Touch events like iOS or Android? The touch events seems will become a standard in W3C: http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webevents/raw-file/tip/touchevents.html. IE 9 said it follow the standards, does anyone know whether it will support touch events? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It currently supports no touch events. All you need do to prove it is something simple like this:

```
document.ontouchstart = function() { alert("TS"); }
document.ontouchmove = function() { alert("TM"); }
document.ontouchend = function() { alert("TE"); }
```

None of these will fire in IE9 mobile.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't currently support touch events.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid - if your answer gets an upvote, then it won't be "below" and longer.  And if someone else adds an answer, it's going to get even more confusing. Remember, this is not a Forum.  Frame your complete answer.  If you have a comment, it should be self contained.  If you disagree with an answer, well that's why there's a downvote option.

Answer (score -2):

This is partially not true. I develop on Windows Phone 7. And I have achieved a touch effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/blackdynamo/yxhzU/

Here, this works on HTC HD7 - mobile version and desktop version selected. You can see the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery Mobile Carousel Demo - jsFiddle demo by blackdynamo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js' jquery.mobile, carousel></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://github.com/blackdynamo/jQuery-Mobile-Carousel/raw/master/jquery.ui.ipad.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://github.com/blackdynamo/jQuery-Mobile-Carousel/raw/master/jquery.mobile.carousel.js"></script>
  <style type='text/css'></style>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
      (function($) {
        $("#carousel1").carousel();
        $("#carousel2").carousel({direction: "vertical"});
    })(jQuery);
  });
  //]]> 
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
Horizontal
<div style="height: 300px; width: 500px">
    <ul id="carousel1" style="display: none;">
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#381;">Page 1</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#837;">Page 2</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#999;">Page 3</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#738;">Page 4</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#142;">Page 5</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#927;">Page 6</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#987;">Page 7</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#187;">Page 8</div>
      </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
Vertical
<div style="height: 300px; width: 500px">
    <ul id="carousel2" style="display: none;">
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#381;">Page 1</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#837;">Page 2</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#999;">Page 3</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#738;">Page 4</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#142;">Page 5</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#927;">Page 6</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#987;">Page 7</div>
      </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#187;">Page 8</div>
      </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does this answer even mean?  "This is not true" is not an answer - it's probably a comment.  The link simply goes to a page with some HTML and JS.  And not a lot of it.  If that HTML is an answer showing touch events working, then post that *HTML* here as the answer.  Don't send us to a linked page that really shows nothing about it working on a phone.

Comment: The question is about the WebBrowsers control for touch EVENTS. Mimicing them with mouse events in javascript is different.

Comment: No. JavaScript can achieve this effect. Stupid down votes by people who have time on their hands.

Comment: I'm not gonna up- or down-vote but I'll mention in passing if it helps that it's pretty clear this does absolutely nothing in the way of demonstrating support for touch events (`touchstart`, `touchmove`, etc.). To say it "works partially" may be ambitious. But hey, that's nice that jQuery carousel works. (totally doesn't answer question) Thanks for trying